# Ubuntu server backup

Tags: server, backup, restore

I have Ubuntu bare-metal server, I want to create a full backup of the server to external storage and use the backup from external storage to load a new server

Notes:
The server is hosted on a remote hosting provider and it is not easy to attach attach any bootable drives or Live CD

how can I do that?

thank you very much in advance, your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This will depend on your host: google/gce, amazon/aws and microsoft/azure all provide a website with a "console"  where you can create backups of containers. Mind that your system is likely protected so it only works using that hosting provider and you can make backups for your personal data/partition but not create a workable system out of that copy.

Comment: This depend on the vendor who provide the server. The best thing to do is to back-up your data snapshot; back-up whatever image your deploy on the server, if you are using engines like docker you will be able to comfortably deploy all your data snapshots and images in any identical system.

Comment: Thank you, but Docker is not used, I am searching for a tool or a proven method that can take a full backup of the system as snapshots, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It is a bare-metal server, not shared with others, there are no virtual machines

Comment: I have previously used some of this tools [link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-backup-linux-snapshots) try one of them, you should be able to copy your serve configurations and media files.

Comment: Thank you for the link